# How to avoid VSTO Outlook add-in from being disabled due to slow start up?

Tags: outlook, vsto

I have an add-in which needs to run some time consuming code during start up, since  Outlook disables slow add-ins, what to avoid this somehow. Are there events I can respond to we don't count in Outlooks calculation of a slow add in? Or is utilizing threads the only way to go? Am a bit worried that threads if not used very carefully may interact badly with Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do anything like that on startup - the easiest workaround is to create a `Timer` object (use the `Timer` object from the `Forms` namespace, not `System` - you want the timer to fire on the main thread) and run your code when the timer event fires. By the time the event fires, you will be out of the startup callback that Outlook monitors, so it will never know. The user would still be blocked of course, so this can be only a temporary band-aid.

You can still use threads in you addin, you just need to make sure you don't touch OOM on the secondary threads. If your time consuming code does not need any Outlook objects, you can easily move it into a secondary thread. Otherwise Extended MAPI (C++ or Dephi only) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - it wraps Extended MAPI and can be used from any language) are your only options. In case of Redemption, you can save the value of the `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT` property in a variable and then on a secondary thread create a new instance of the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object (it roughly corresponds to the Namespace object in OOM) and set its `MAPIOBJECT` property to the value saved on the main thread.

Comment: thanks, I've built several VSTO add-ins already and sometimes people complained about that, another thing is that somewhere I read that Forms timer should be used only for short time processing, and if we need a long period of processing we should opt for System.Timer instead and I have such a situation that I have to process new appointments all the time, so I use System.Timer there and it works (for the moment :))

Comment: System.Timer will fire on its own thread, and you cannot use Outlook Object Model objects on secondary threads in an addin. If you don't touch OOM, then it is perfectly fine of course - but then you don't need to use a timer, an explicit thread or a task would work.

Comment: actually, I am using the timer to pull appointments in regular intervals and check them based on some rules

Comment: Then it must be the main thread using Forms.Timer. If you want to do that on a secondary thread, it is either Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption.